# How to add a dynamic button in an external java class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-button

I am having problems with creating public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) in another java class.For this reason i cant create a dynamic button in java.I don't know what to do..
this is my java class

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 856;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 480;
    public static final int MOVESPEED = -5;
    private long smokeStartTime;
    private long missileStartTime;
    private MainThread thread;
    private Background bg;
    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Smokepuff> smoke;
    private ArrayList<Missile> missiles;
    private ArrayList<TopBorder> topborder;
    private ArrayList<BotBorder> botborder;
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int maxBorderHeight;
    private int minBorderHeight;
    private boolean topDown = true;
    private boolean botDown = true;
    private boolean newGameCreated;

    public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
    }
```

this is my main java which has contentView of this java class..

```
public class Game extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //turn title off
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //set to full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));

    }
```

Please help me to find a solution and create a dynamic button in the GamePanel java class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //in your activity add this for button
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_tags);

    //set the properties for button
    Button btnTag = new Button(this);
    btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnTag.setText("Button");
    btnTag.setId(some_random_id);

    //add button to the layout
    layout.addView(btnTag);
```

Comment: it says cannot resolve symbol (id) ... besides The GamePanel.java is an external class.it doesn't have any layout..most of the game runs in this because The main Game.java shows the GAmePanel.java by   .....setContentView(new GamePanel(this));